# The Android system can access the microphone when it is used?

Tags: security, camera, hardware, privacy, microphone

The android blocks multiple aplications using the microphone at same time, for example, but the internal apps or the system can have access to it even on use?

I'm asking this question because I want to prevent mic uses from apps that I don't want to.

For example: the Android system can interface the hardware to apps, blocking the most apps, but Google apps, for example, can access any time